python `getpass.getuser()` on Windows to UTF-8
We are working with Windows computers. User names are based on real names, and so might contain accents (like, in my case 'MichaëlHooreman').
Windows machines are using CP1252 encoding. I'm using getpass.getuser() to get user name and then report them in HTML documents. Unfortunately, the result is in CP1252 and not UTF8, so encoding problems...
I don't want to encode HTML in CP1252.
I've tried the following python code:
import getpass
import locale
import sys

f = locale.getpreferredencoding()
t = sys.getdefaultencoding()
r = getpass.getuser()
if f != t:
    print(f"converting from {f} to {t}")
    print(f"{r=}")
    b = r.encode(f)
    print(f"{b=}")
    r = b.decode(t)
    print(f"{r=}")
print(r)

... and it's not working ...
converting from cp1252 to utf-8
r='MichaëlHooreman'
b=b'Micha\xeblHooreman'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\projects\xlvalrep\testuser.py", line 13, in <module>
    r = b.decode(t)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 5: invalid continuation byte

After time spent in internet, no solution so far...
How can I fix this?
Thanks!

I'm not sure how this code is related to HTML. If you need to generate a UTF-8 encoded file, open the file with open(..., mode='w', encoding='utf-8'). Anyway, this is missing a [mcve]

getpass returns a Unicode string. It isn’t in a particular encoding. There is nothing to convert. If you want the result in UTF-8, use r.encode()

The result of getpass.getuser() is a str (Unicode string) that is made up of Unicode code points with no encoding.  Just encode the string the the encoding you want.
What you have done is encode in CP1252 and decode in UTF-8 resulting in an error.  You can only decode bytes using the encoder they were encoded in.
Example:
r = 'MichaëlHooreman'
print(f'Unicode:', r)
print(f'CP1252: ', r.encode('cp1252'))
print(f'UTF-8:  ', r.encode())  # encode's default is 'utf8'

Output:
Unicode: MichaëlHooreman
CP1252:  b'Micha\xeblHooreman'
UTF-8:   b'Micha\xc3\xablHooreman'

